# Limit number of nodes that can exist of a certain content type based on CCK term reference field input

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I have a content type with an autocomplete term reference field.  I want to control the number of nodes that can exist as published with the same term reference.  Any number of these nodes would be able to be created, published, unpublished and deleted, but only a specific number would be able to exist as published at any given time.

It looks like this module doesn't quite do this:  [Node Limit](http://drupal.org/project/node_limit)

Comment: Have you try the patch for [node_limit taxonomy terms](http://drupal.org/node/423860) ?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!  I have tried the patch, but it's not completely functional.  It adds a term field to admin, but it doesn't even save the term entered.